# getHibernateTemplate().update doesn't update

Tags: hibernate

I'm new with Hibernate, I've successfully selected and inserted into my DB, but the Update doesn't work.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void updateService(ServiceDsite serv) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        getHibernateTemplate().setCheckWriteOperations(false);

        Pays pa=new Pays();
         pa=(Pays)getHibernateTemplate().load(Pays.class,1);

        System.out.println(pa.getNomPays());
        pa.setNomPays("USA");
        getHibernateTemplate().update(pa);}
```

but it doesn't work, without errors

Comment: You are using so many methods to update class.So please paste the methods  getHibernateTemplate

Comment: getHibernateTemplate() is a predefined function in HibernateDaoSupport

Comment: sry , I am not aware of this function.

Comment: turn on hibernate log and share the stack trace here.

Answer (score 1):

**getHibernateTemplate()** is spring framework method. Usage of any direct spring framework template classes/methods will leads to **coupling** of spring framework with your application. The key intention of spring is decoupling and it has been implemented in such a way to decouple the spring itself from the application as much as possible. Using above method is **not recommended** for above mentioned reasons since its affects the **probability** of your dao class. 
Try it with hibernate session interface. The above cases are not the reason for your actual problem.

try this

```
   HibernateTemplate template =  getHibernateTemplate();
    Pays pa =(Pays)template.load(Pays.class,1);
    System.out.println(pa.getNomPays());
    pa.setNomPays("USA");
    template.update(pa);
```

Comment: Thank's for you answer , it didnt work ,
I changed it to this  getHibernateTemplate().bulkUpdate("update Pays ....." ); and it works Thank's anyway